# MYSQL query Create field Y o N based with join two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables; `EVENTS` and `USER` and `USER_HAS_EVENT`.

```
EVENTS : idEvents - name
```

[image: Event Table]
    USER : idUser - name
[image: User Table]

```
USER_HAS_EVENT : idUser - idEvent
```

[image: user_has_event table]

I'd like to select all event from Event's table and create conditionally field (ex.name for new dynamically field = prenotated) that is Y or N if exist a record for single events in `USER_HAS_EVENT` for a determinate `UserId`.

[image: Example and expected result]
[image: Example Result]

the userid is sent in the query dynamically from php , is a parameter in a query.

Sorry For the bad english.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Your English seems fine enough. The problem is it may not be enough to *explain* what the output should look like; instead, it would be better to *show* it. Please update your question with samples of data and the desired result to illustrate your requirement.

Comment: @Andriy M : Thank you again. I tried to add sample data and its expected response. I hope it will go well. –

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. As you've provided different table and column names in your examples you might not be able to use my suggestion directly.

As you want all events with or without a reservation by a given user I would prefer a left join assuming a user can reserve a event only once. Subselect, union or group by constructs are other alternatives.

The isnull-function in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) results in 1 or 0 instead of Y or N in your example. I actually wasn't able to test it, but it will probably do the job:

```
select
    e.id,
    e.name,
    isnull(r.user_id) as 'reserved'
from
    event e left join reservation r on e.id = r.event_id
where
    r.user_id = 56
or
    r.user_id is null
```

The first expression in the where clause restricts to our given user, the second expression ensures that also events without reservation by this user (or any) will be returned. Of course, the user_id should be a parameter in your code.